# The group by is getting rid of some of the rows?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have this query

```
SELECT *, bp.product_id 
FROM builder_product as bp 
JOIN builder_step as bs 
    ON bs.builder_id=bp.builder_id  
JOIN builder as b 
    ON b.builder_id=bs.builder_id 
WHERE b.business_id = '60' 
GROUP BY product_id 
ORDER BY bs.step_number
```

which is grabbing all the products from the `builder_product` table and all looks ok but on closer look the data is missing a few records and all the names are the same.

Here is the [data and the schema](http://pastie.org/2799687) and basically what I want is a query that gives me all the products from the `builder_product` table and the corresponding name from the `builder_step` table with the `business_id` of 60 from the `builder table`.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong and how to avoid duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear from your schema whether `builder_product` and `builder_step` are related by `builder_id` or by `builder_step_id`.  If you clarify that I'll modify the answer below.

You aren't performing any aggregate functions (`SUM(), COUNT(), AVG()`) so you have no need for a `GROUP BY`. Instead you just have a couple of `JOIN`s to perform:

```
SELECT
  bp.*,
  bs.name
FROM 
  builder_product bp
  JOIN builder_step bs ON bp.builder_step_id = bs.builder_step_id
  JOIN builder b ON bp.builder_id = b.builder_id
WHERE b.business_id = 60
```

The duplicates are a result of attempting to `SELECT *` without specifying a table name/alias.  Instead, `SELECT bp.*, bs.name` indicates that specifically all columns from `builder_product` should be returned, plus the `builder_name` column from `builder_step`.

Comment: i did that and it returns 176 records and i only have 22 products ...am i missing something

Comment: thats why i did the group by because of this query returning 176 rows

Comment: they are related by builder_step_id

Comment: @Tamer Probably the wrong join condition between bs & bp. Try edit above.

Answer (score 1):

You should not select rows that are not listed in the group by clause.
MySQL allows this, but there are pittfals.
Most other SQL's give an error on your query.

Rewrite it to:

```
SELECT bp.*, bs.*, b.* 
FROM FROM builder_product as bp
INNER JOIN builder_step as bs ON bs.builder_id=bp.builder_id  
INNER JOIN builder as b ON b.builder_id=bs.builder_id 
WHERE bp.product_id IN 
  (
  SELECT bp1.product_id 
  FROM builder_product as bp1 
  JOIN builder_step as bs1 ON bs1.builder_id = bp1.builder_id  
  JOIN builder as b1 ON b1.builder_id = bs1.builder_id 
  WHERE b1.business_id = '60' 
  GROUP BY bp1.product_id 
  )
  AND b.business_id = '60'
ORDER BY bs.step_number
```